# Apache - .HTACCESS applies previous conditions to current rewrite url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

My .htaccess applies `RewriteCond`'s from previous `RewriteRule`'s  to the current `RewriteRule`.

For example `example.com/acme` gets redirected to `http://www.example.com/index.php?url=acme`.

Why would this configuration ever redirect to `index.php`? The `index.php`'s `RewriteRule` isn't even a `R=301`. And the `RewriteCond`'s that makes exceptions when the `request_uri` contains the string `acme` shouldn't even be applying themselves to this `RewriteRule` since they have their own `RewriteRule`.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(txt) [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} robots\.txt
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !acme
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(txt) [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} robots\.txt
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=off
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems lke it executed 2 rewrite rules at the same time. Adding the `[END]` flag fixed the issue.